# DSview 4 Break Sequence

Tags: cisco

one of our customers is using DSview 4 as a terminal server solution.
I have the problem that I want to send a CTRL+Break to one of our routers.
Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. I tried CTRL+Break and the "special commands -> BREAK"
from Putty. In the DSview 4 documentation they write the following about escape sequences:

> The default escape sequence is ^Ec, which can be followed by an escape
> key to send a command to a target device.
>
> From an SSH Passthrough session, enter a command in the following
> format: ^Ec[escape key] For example: ^Ecl? displays the break sequence
> list.

Can someone tell me which key or key combination *^Ec* and *^Ecl?* is?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards
tLanze

Comment: Have you tried *Ctrl-Esc* or just *Esc*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like it's a conserver implementation, which uses `Ctrl`-`E` followed by `c` as its escape sequence. See https://www.conserver.com/docs/console.man.html#ESCAPE%20SEQUENCES for some more info.